# How to deploy .VMX to vCenter using Linux CLI tool?

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

I need to deploy a .VMX VM to vCenter using a Linux CLI tool.

For a long time, I have been using `ovftool` for this purpose, which worked well enough.  However, recently I found that `ovftool` is internally converting the VMX to `ova`, and so it loses important directives in the VMX file.  In particular, `ethernet0.pciSlotNumber` is lost, which has the unfortunate effect of changing the interface name of the ethernet card in Linux.

Are there any automated solutions that will simply upload the .VMX (and VMDK) files without converting them?

Comment: Has the .vmx been created with vCenter or with a different VMware product?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider It was created with packer